# SUMPRODUCT dynamic columns with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, dynamic

Attached is the screenshot of the data.

What I am trying to do is to sum all the criterias that match and sum the columns dynamically.

I believe the picture describes what I'd like to accomplish.

[image]

For clarity, given the structure of the data, what I'd like to do is to sum the relevant columns (Actuals per desired date) as well as other criterias.

In this example, I'd like to sum only for the Actuals from Feb 2016 to Apr 2016 for "USA", "John" and "Milk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$14=$A$3:$A$8)*($B$15=$B$3:$B$8)*($B$16=$C$3:$C$8)*($B$17=$E$2:$P$2)*($B$18<=$E$1:$P$1)*($C$18>=$E$1:$P$1)*($E$3:$P$8))
```

that should do